# Should I use HornetQ JMS API to integrate with Spring TransactionManager?

Tags: spring, transactions, jms, hornetq

I have a basic doubt regarding Transactions and the HornetQ native API.

If my application is Spring-based, with Spring managed transactions, how should I configure HornetQ to participate in the same transaction managed by Spring (AOP)?

Using the JMS API I guess it's fairly obvious, since Spring considers JMS resources as transactional.

But I don't know how to do it correctly using the nativa API. Could someone shed a light on this problem?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HornetQ supports XA on the core API, they are just resources.

You should be able to enlist these resources on Spring if that's just using regular XA API.

http://docs.jboss.org/hornetq/2.2.5.Final/api/org/hornetq/api/core/client/ClientSession.html

I'm not sure though how that integration is done on Spring. If there's anything not working it could (and should) be fixed or improved on a spring-integration module.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I understand correctly, but if you're trying to simply do declarative transaction managment using Spring and the @Transactional annotation for JUST JMS, then simply use the <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager = "myTransactionManager" /> and then - for the "myTranactionManager," register a bean of type JmsTransactionManager, e.g.,

```
@Bean public PlatformTransactionManager myTranactionManager (){ 
  return new JmsTransactionManager( this.connectionFactory());
}
```

Now, you can use the annotation as normal and the JMS interactions will be wrapped in a transaction

```
@Transactional
public void doSomethingWithJms(){ 
  jmsTemplate.send(...);
  jmsTemplate.convertAndSend(...)
}
```

If your goal is to work with MULTIPLE resources, e.g., JMS *and* JDBC, then you need to use JTA. To see how to setup JTA (for JPA *and* JMS), check out this blog post http://blog.springsource.com/2011/08/15/configuring-spring-and-jta-without-full-java-ee/